# how to define jquery UI sortable draggable area?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

I would like to know how to specify the draggable area of jquery ui sortable plugin?
I have created multiple blocks and I want to make it sortable by this:

```
$('.itemsWrapper').sortable({
            startPos: null,
            endPos: null,
            start: function(event, ui) {
                this.startPos = ui.item.index();
            },
            stop: function(event, ui) {
                this.endPos = ui.item.index();
                __this.onReorder.emit({ from: this.startPos, to: this.endPos });
            }
        }).disableSelection();
```

In general, it worked fine, but after I put a map to be draggable, the whole map becomes draggable, this behavior is wrong because user still want to move the map contents without making the whole map to change order.

I put an icon on the top of the map, I want to enforce the dragging behavior only happened when user is dragging that icon.

but how to make this happen? I checked the jquery UI sortable, but can not find out solution.

Thanks in advance for your suggestions

Comment: Sounds like you want to define the `handle` option in sortable.

Comment: exactly! Thanks for your quick answer.